# Unity 5.4 Animator's Animation/States Play/Stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How possible to play animations or states in Animators with C# (non Legacy)?

Animations Clips "RightAnim" and "LeftAnim"

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class AnimatorPS: MonoBehaviour
     {
      Animator anim;
        int left=Animator.StringToHash("LeftAnim");
        int right=Animator.StringToHash("RightAnim");


     voidStart()
      {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.SetTrigger (left);
      }

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Attach an "Animator" component to an Empty game Object . And choose a Controller from Inspector that you have created for your "Left","Right" animations. Also make sure you have made transitions properly by opening Window->Animator.

Attach this script to that Empty Game Object:

```
  int left=Animator.StringToHash("leftAnim");
  int right=Animator.StringToHash("rightAnim");
  void Start(){
  GetComponent<Animator).SetTrigger(left);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did but is not working. I updated above code with new screenshot.

Comment: I checked in Animator, there is no parameters there is 2 layers "RightAnim" and "LeftAnim"

Comment: please make transition from Entry to Right Anim....
and test by playing this would yield if our animations are working properly.
Then click on Right Anim and in Inspector window,check if there is something in "Motion" value. If there is not, create an Animation for the Object and then drag that here.

Comment: also, I don't think in your case you need to have multiple layers. Just use a single Base Layer.

Comment: When run LeftAnim play, but codes not working. I can't change direction with codes.

Comment: Parameter 'Hash 892365796' does not exist.

Comment: I think the way you are implementing the animations have some problem..
Because I've tested the script and is working.

Comment: I think i need create parameters no?